# Object detection performance with single multi-class model vs. multiple single-class models for multiple categories

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am trying to detect multiple objects such as road signs, pedestrians etc using Tensorflow object detection. However I am unsure whether to have a single model for each object type or have a single model which can detect multiple object types.
How does performance in terms of accuracy, resource consumption etc. vary with each approach? Are there any other factors to consider?

Answer (score 2):

Single model which can detect multiple object types is a better choice, because the speed will be N times faster than N models, memory usage will also be reduced by N times, and the accuracy will be about the same.

Comment: I see, does the distribution of training data across the various classes affect the accuracy of the detections?

Comment: It will affect, but it depends on the difficulty of the problem. For example, it is more difficult to distinguish between two kinds of cars, and it is less difficult to distinguish between cats and dogs. You can increase your sample size through data agument.